# Como selecionar uma porta para se conectar com SQL-Server Remoto

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Estou com o seguinte problema, meu servidor SQL está com a porta 1433 aberta e comunicando corretamente, mas o meu cliente tem um firewall que bloqueia todas as portas de entrada e de saída dos computadores ligados na rede. Ai vem o problema, preciso conectar nesse servidor mas eu não encontrei aonde consigo escolher qual porta eu vou usar. Além disso, verificando as portas abertas em um computador, conectado em outra rede, conectado no servidor, verifiquei que as mesmas são dinâmicas e eu não tenho a possibilidade de desbloquear todas as portas do meu cliente. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como proceder? Não postei nenhum código pois não encontrei nada aonde eu pudesse mudar na minha `connectionString` ou na minha `SqlConnection`.

tldr: Meu SQL-Server está com todas as portas abertas, mas o meu cliente tem todas as SUAS portas fechadas, como eu escolho com quais portas meu cliente vai usar para conectar na minha porta 1433 do servidor?

Comment: Por desencargo, existe outro terminal no cliente que consegue acessar seu servidor SQL Server ?

Comment: Não, todas as máquinas têm todas as portas bloqueadas, apenas as que eles abrem especificamente. O jeito vai ser usar uma conexão 3G para isso eu acho, visto que a empresa não quer abrir todas as portas para uma estação apenas ( eu concentraria todas as requisições de banco lá, criando um WebService e acessando ele pela rede deles mesmo).

Answer (score 2):

No seu `connectionString`, põe uma vírgula depois do IP/servidor. Por exemplo:

```xml
<connectionString Server="128.0.0.1,6000" ... />
```

Assim, você está especificando exatamente a porta para contectar. Agora, se o cliente tem **todas** as portas bloqueadas, você vai ter que inventar um outro tipo de solução.